# Was the text on the magazine cover intentional?

Tags: props, weird-science

The 1985 film [*Weird Science*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090305/) shows two teenage boys (Gary and Wyatt) creating a woman with their computer.  In the process of creating the perfect woman, they insert several photos into their computer for data.

One particular photo that they insert shows what looks like a magazine cover with a photo of Kelly LeBrock who is the actress portraying "Lisa" (the girl that the two boys ultimately create)

There appears to be what looks like the words "Lisa" and "Talks" to the right of the photograph.

[image]

[image]

Later in the movie, Gary suggests the name "Lisa" to be given to her as her name.

Out of universe, [Kelly LeBrock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_Le_Brock) was a model before becoming an actress and was on the cover of several magazines.

Is there any evidence that this magazine cover existed out of universe?  Did filmmakers choose to name the character based on the text that was on the magazine or was this simply created for the film with those specific words on it?

Comment: It might help to identify the magazine. Later in the scene, we see more of the top of the picture. It seems to say "TEM", possibly part of a magazine cover?

Comment: @Valorum I can't seem to see it.  I played the scene back and I cannot see the letter "T" anywhere.  Maybe I am just blind ;)

Comment: Just after this shot is another shot of a keyboard (with hands), then you see Wyatt feeding the magazine cover into the slot. That's when you can see the extra letter

Comment: @Valorum Okay.  I see what you mean now :)

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that's it was a mock up made for the movie, so the text would be deliberate. It doesn't match any of her covers I've found posted on the web. I did find this scan of a magazine page that appears to use the same photograph, although I haven't been able to source it.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that this is from Playboy judging by the photo as well as her "interests" listed.  The only other thing that I can think of would be a health and fitness magazine.  The inset black and white photo also looks "Playboy-ish" to me, so, I don't know.